# Jenkins Docker Push to google cloud fails with an exception

Tags: jenkins, docker, push, google-cloud-platform, docker-registry

I'm building a docker image via jenkins and want to deploy it to google cloud registry using the jenkins plugin (docker-build-step, Google Container Registry Auth Plugin, Google OAuth Credentials plugin), using the following instructions: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Container+Registry+Auth+Plugin

I have a VM instance on GCE where I have both jenkins and docker installed.
The build works OK, but it fails when I'm trying to push it to the Registry:

```
Successfully built c2ddc81c66d1

[Docker] INFO: Sucessfully created image eu.gcr.io/$project-id/base
[Docker] INFO: Pushing image eu.gcr.io/$project-id/base
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 127.0.0.1:2375 failed to respond
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
```

--

But when I try to push it via SSH, it works:

```
bash-4.2$ whoami
jenkins
bash-4.2$ gcloud docker push eu.gcr.io/$project-id/base
The push refers to a repository [eu.gcr.io/$project-id/base]
41772e41ab05: Layer already exists 
a03f60753e4e: Pushing [=========>                                         ] 9.223 MB/47.44 MB
```

I believe that if it was some kind of scope from the google VM, I shouldn't be able to do it via ssh either. Could it be the jenkins user environment variables?

Anyone has a working configuration for a similar scenario? Anyone that knows Jenkins well knows what kind of config could be causing this?

Also, before using http://127.0.0.1:2375 as the docker url, I had unix:///var/run/docker.sock, and with that configuration, instead of "127.0.0.1:2375 no HttpResponseExpcetion" I had "localhost:80 no HttpResponseExpcetion" on the log, so using the socket isn't the solution either.

Regards,
JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related with **failed a connection between Jenkins and Google Registry**. I'm assuming there's no problem with the network connection, since it's calling the localhost.

```
[Docker] INFO: Sucessfully created image eu.gcr.io/$project-id/base
[Docker] INFO: Pushing image eu.gcr.io/$project-id/base
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 127.0.0.1:2375 failed to respond
```

So, that leaves us with an applicational problem. Check your **Google oAuth credentials**, it can be an **unauthorized access exception** being throwed, in which you'll have to create the credentials.

In any case, check your logs and elevate the log level to see if there's any important info that went unnoticed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the heads-up! After your comment I enabled the debug level on docker and I saw the unauthorized access exception again. After this I double-checked my credentials. They seemed fine but I went to google registry, created a new account and downloaded a JSON for that account.
After this I created a new account on jenkins using that JSON file and voila, the docker push works! Thanks for the heads-up!